# How to Switch Views at Runtime?

Tags: android, user-interface, view, android-activity, runtime

I have the following code in my accounting application:

```
// switch View to the Customer layout, widget id's are the same on both layouts
private void hideExpenseView() {
    setContentView(R.layout.customer_invoices);
}

// switch View to the Supplier layout
private void hideIncomeView() {
    setContentView(R.layout.supplier_invoices);
}
```

The above does not work, as when you switch the ContentView, you lose all variable mappings. You have to map variables after you setContentView() unfortunately.

If this worked, this would be a beautifully simple solution for my app. See, I've named the widgets in both xml layouts the same ids. Instead of hiding elements of one xml layout based on different states, I switch the entire View to the appropriate layout - whether entering a Customer sales invoice, or a Supplier expense invoice.

By switching Views, I would have basically 6 lines of code taking care of the UI transition, very simple.

I hope this is still possible in another capacity, can someone please push me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe you try to do this with fragments?
Two fragments extends one base fragment. All logic is implemented in base fragment and derived fragments just creating diffrent views.

Comment: I want to keep the app under the Froyo 2.2 (API 8) framework.

Comment: You can keep it. Just use support library. It works 7+.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I did not know, I will check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out ViewSwitcher : see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html

That, or base your activities layout in a framelayout that includes supplier_invoices.xml and customer_invoices.xml.  Then your homegrown hide-n-show will be g2g.  Tho, you might need to change the ids still.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your views in two `LinearLayouts`, one for `R.layout.customer_invoices` and another for `R.layout.supplier_invoices`.

You need to implement your own findViewById.

```
private static final int LAYOUT_EXPENSE = 1;
private static final int LAYOUT_INCOME = 2;

private int currentLayout = LAYOUT_EXPENSE;

private LinearLayout expenseContainer, incomeContainer;

// switch View to the Customer layout, widget id's are the same on both layouts
private void hideExpenseView() {
    switchLayout(LAYOUT_INCOME);
}

// switch View to the Supplier layout
private void hideIncomeView() {
    switchLayout(LAYOUT_EXPENSE);    
}

private void switchLayout(int layout) {
    currentLayout = layout;
    if (layout == LAYOUT_EXPENSE) { 
        expenseContainer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        incomeContainer.setVisibility(GONE);
    } else {
        expenseContainer.setVisibility(GONE);
        incomeContainer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
}

public View findViewById(int id) {
    if (layout == LAYOUT_EXPENSE) return expenseContainer.findViewById(id);
    else return incomeContainer.findViewById(id);
}
```

I think you got my idea.

Comment: Not so right ) I think @forgivegod 's solution is more correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/customer_invoices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- put customer_invoices related tools like TextView, Button, ImageView here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/supplier_invoices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- put supplier_invoices related tools like TextView, Button, ImageView here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Java code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    View supplier_invoices,customer_invoices;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        supplier_invoices = findViewById(R.id.supplier_invoices);

        customer_invoices = findViewById(R.id.customer_invoices);

        }


     // switch View to the Customer layout, widget id's are the same on both layouts
        private void hideExpenseView() {
            setContentView(R.layout.customer_invoices);
            customer_invoices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            supplier_invoices.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        // switch View to the Supplier layout
        private void hideIncomeView() {

            supplier_invoices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customer_invoices.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Tried this, however, this means I have to define two sets of variable for each widget, one for the customer view widget and one for the supplier view widget. I am trying to avoid the clutter defining all of these variables will create.